# VB.Net - Webbrowser, Open In New Tab Navigation Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, tabcontrol

I'm working on a web browser In VB (IE engine, I will use GeckoFX later, probably) and I have overriden the deafult Context Menu using my custom one, which includes an "Open In New Tab" button.

When the user clicks the button, it creates another `TabPage` with another web browser inside which navigates to the link from the previous web browser.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem2.Click
    Dim x1 As New TabPage
    Dim B1 As New WebBrowser
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(x1)
    TabControl1.SelectTab(x1)
    B1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False
    B1.ContextMenuStrip = Open
    B1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(B1)
    Dim Elem As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim target As String = Elem.GetAttribute("href")
    B1.Navigate(target)
End Sub
```

However, due to this line:

```
Dim Elem As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
```

the new `WebBrowser` component will navigate to the correct link if the user opens it from the first web browser (`WebBrowser1`). Thus, if the user is on the second web browser and opens a new tab, the third web browser will navigate where the second web browser already is. So, how should I fix this?

With what should I replace `WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement`??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please Use Correct Word Casing Or Else This Gets Very Annoying To Read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently referring to `WebBrowser1` every time. To refer to the current web browser you must first get the selected tab, then you can get the `WebBrowser` inside that `TabPage`.

If you only have a `WebBrowser` control in your tab page, or you know that the control always has the same index you can do like this:

```
Dim Elem As HtmlElement = DirectCast(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls(0), WebBrowser).Document.ActiveElement
```

Using `DirectCast` you cast the `SelectedTab`'s first control to a `WebBrowser`.

`SelectedTab.Controls` is a collection of all the controls in the container. The first control is accessed via index 0 (therefore the 0 in `SelectedTab.Controls(0)`).

Comment: I get an error saying: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Comment: @AndrewGeo : Right. Put it before your `TabControl1.SelectTab(x1)` line and it should work.

Comment: @AndrewGeo : You're welcome! I've done a lot of things in the web browser category (adding tabs is one of the first) so I see many similarities with what I've done once back in time. :)

Comment: While reading your comment I thought that you might be able to answer few questions in the near future. Then I opened my project only to realize that I could not think of a way of getting the navigated pages of a new web browser control (for updating history, changing tab.text and such). So, can you guide me through this one, and should I start a new topic?
P.S. Saying that there are similarities between our codes is actually a compliment since I'm 16 and I've been programming in VB.Net for as little as a year or so :)

Comment: @AndrewGeo : Well I'm 17 and I've been programming in VB since 8 years, and VB.NET since 7 :). For helping you with your request it'd be easier to continue through e-mail. --- If you go into my Stack Overflow profile and to my website _(beware of the background sound)_ and then into the **Support** section, you can find my support e-mail there.

Comment: @AndrewGeo : Otherwise, if you do not want to e-mail me I recommend you to ask a new question. **What I can tell you in the meantime** is that to change the text of the tab, etc., you should subscribe to a web browser's `DocumentCompleted` event, and update everything there. It can be done like this: `AddHandler B1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted`. _This would of course require a sub called `WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted` with the correct parameters._